# React Native: change State from different component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm quite new to React-Native. I have a screen, that is getting information from my service in json format and is displaying the data after that. On that screen, I have a component "Calendar", from which the user can pick up another date. I don't know how to update the predictions-state from that component.

Here is my HomeScreen:

```
export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {

  const [predictions, setPredictions] = useState([]);
  const [params, setParams] = useState({
    lang: 'en',
    date: '2020-10-11',
    sport: 'soccer'
  });

  useEffect( () => {
    loadPredictions();
  }, []);

  const loadPredictions = async () => {
    const response = await PredictionsApi.getPredictions({params});
    // console.log(response.data);
    setPredictions(response.data);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.main}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Calendar />
          ...
        </View>
    </View>
}
```

Here is my Calendar Component:

```
function renderDates({props}) {
    const dates = [];
    for(let i=-2;i<4;++i) {
        var currentDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * i * 1000);
        dates.push(
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.dates} onPress={()=> props.setPredictions({
                lang: 'en',
                date: '2020-02-01',
                sport: 'tennis',
            })
            }>
                <Text style={styles.selected}>{Moment(currentDate).format('ddd')}{"\n"}{Moment(currentDate).format('DD')}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
    return dates;
}

export default function Calendar({props}) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.calendarContainer}>
            ...
            <View style={styles.second}>
                {renderDates({props})}
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are quite a few things I would recommend you do differently in this code. However, to answer your question, you can pass the `setPredictions` function down as a prop, and then call it with `props.setPredictions()` in your `Calendar` component.

A simple example of this idea would be:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const parentFunction = () => console.log('Hello from parent');

  return <Child parentFunction={parentFunction} />;
};


// clicking the div in this child will call the function defined in Parent
const Child = ({parentFunction}) => <div onClick={parentFunction}>Click me</div>;
```

You can use this same principle for all of your functions that set state in the parent as well.

I'll stop here. If you have questions about how this applies to your code just ask. And if you want further advice on the rest of your code, let me know. Thanks.

Here is my attempt to address some of the concerns I have with your code. I think your issue was caused by incorrect destructuring of props, and also that you didn't actually seem to be using setting your predictions anywhere in the child components, or calling your API. I hope this makes sense:

```
// use const instead of function - more conventional
const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const [predictions, setPredictions] = useState([]);
  const [params, setParams] = useState({
    lang: 'en',
    date: '2020-10-11',
    sport: 'soccer',
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    loadPredictions();
  }, []);

  const loadPredictions = async () => {
    const response = await PredictionsApi.getPredictions({params});
    // console.log(response.data);
    setPredictions(response.data);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.main}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {/* Pass load predictions and setParams to Calendar as props */}
        <Calendar loadPredictions={loadPredictions} setParams={setParams} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

// destructuring should be used to get the individual props. If you put {props} then
// the implication is you would be using `props.props.theActualProp`
// so either remove the curly braces or destructure the actual props
// you want to use
const Calendar = props => (
  <View style={styles.calendarContainer}>
    <View style={styles.second}>
      {/* pass all the props down to Dates component */}
      {/* I also changed this to an element, since there is no reason to do otherwise */}
      <Dates {...props} />
      {/* I added a button here so you can actually reload the predictions */}
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.loadPredictions}>Load new predictions</TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </View>
);

// only destructure if you are pulling individual props OUT of the `props` object
const Dates = props => {
  // don't use for loops inside a function like this... it's cleaner to use the `map` method
  // on an array

  // cache the current time once per render if you need to
  const cachedTime = new Date().getTime();

  // I'm not sure why these particular numbers are important, or what you're trying to do here
  // I've preserverd the behaviour from your for loop, but depending on what you're trying
  // to achieve there is probably a more sensible solution to this
  return [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4].map(val => {
    const rowDate = new Date(cachedTime + 24 * 60 * 60 * val * 1000);

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        // add a key when mapping over an array
        key={val}
        style={styles.dates}
        onPress={() =>
          // I changed this to setParams. I think this is what you meant, since
          // setPredictions should only be form your API response?
          props.setParams({
            lang: 'en',
            date: '2020-02-01',
            sport: 'tennis',
          })
        }
      >
        <Text style={styles.selected}>
          {Moment(rowDate).format('ddd')}
          {'\n'}
          {Moment(rowDate).format('DD')}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you @James, i got the idea, but i am facing problems to implement it. I realized that setPredictions() is updating the predictions variable with the json-data. So in my Calendar i need to call the loadPredictions() with the choosen date and that is the hard part :(

Comment: I've added my version of your code and tried to explain the changes I made. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: you are great. It is working :) I have just removed the button which calls loadPredictions(), it is called by clicking the dates with the selected date as a parameter and is working as I wish :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use setState and read the documentation firstly

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate